# i couldn't alert javascript and call header location back to back how to do that

Tags: javascript, php

```
$sql="UPDATE `youtube` SET `yid`='$id',`ypage`='$page',`yframe`='$yvideo',`ytitle`='$title',`ydate`='$date' WHERE yid='$id'";
    $result=sqlquery($sql);

    if($result)

    {
        echo "<script>alert('your video has been uploaded');</script>";
        header('location:videoupload.php');
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible if you are using `header()` as the redirect with JS Alert.. Because the headers are already sent and you won't see the alertbox. Instead this will work.

```
echo "<script>alert('your video has been uploaded');</script>";
//header('location:videoupload.php');
echo "<script>window.location.href='videoupload.php'</script>";
exit;
```

But a Javascript redirect is not at all recommended !